# How to remove default value '0' in django forms using css only

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-forms

I'm making django forms which requires a default value while making migrations into it but I want to show this :"--------" by default, not 0 using css only:
my django form looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-12">
      <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        <a href="{% url 'employee:products_table' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button">Nevermind</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

In this img, Instead of showing 0 I want "------", but must be done only with css.

Comment: Please show us the form you are using.

Comment: You can not change the HTML with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some JS.. Add this JS code.

```
var inputText = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {
  if(inputText[i].value == 0){
    inputText[i].value = '--------';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with pure CSS.

Instead, check out how to manipulate with separate HTML elements inside crispy Django forms and make it so that the value of the `input` element is empty and the `placeholder` attribute is "------" just as you want it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a webkit pseudo class available in CSS used in conjunction with the content attribute to set the placeholder.

```
.my-input-class::-webkit-input-placeholder::before {
   color:#6B6A6A;
   content:"------";
}
```

Just noting this again: This is for webkit browsers only.